# Arrays in board game program

Tags: c, arrays

So, I have been trying to program this game, in which the user has to enter the score he wants to play to. I would like to do this with an array so I did what you can see below (`score[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0}`).

But somehow I get, when I use score[relplayers(a counter in the array, so the programm passes turns)] = score[relplayers](the old score) + thrown (value of the dice i rolled); I have no idea why this doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>



int throwing () {

srand(time(NULL));

int value = rand() % 6 + 1;

return value;

}



int main() {

int abplayers, relplayers, thrown, playersshown, abscore, rounds;
printf("Enter the number of fields: ");
scanf("%d", abscore);
int score [4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

for (rounds = 0; rounds < 50; rounds++)
{
    for(relplayers = 0; relplayers < 4; relplayers++)

    {

        int playershown = relplayers + 1;
        getchar();
        thrown = throwing();
        printf("\nPlayer nº%d threw a %d", playershown, thrown);
        score[relplayers] = score[relplayers] + thrown;
        printf("\nPlayer nº%d is in %d field", playershown, score);
        if (score[relplayers] >= abscore)
        {
            printf("Player nº%d won", playershown);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Another problem with that program are special fields. I wanted to include these fields so that the player gets trapped in these fields or gets boosted up in these. I have tried to put this in my program, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
int enter() {
int allscore;
printf("Number of fields: ");
scanf("%d", allscore);
return allscore;
}

int badfields () {
  int abscore;
  srand(time(NULL));
  abscore = enter();
  int numbers[10] = {rand() % abscore + 1};
  return numbers;
}
int goodfields () {
 int abscore;
 srand(time(NULL));
 abscore = enter();
 int fields[10] = {rand() % abscore + 1};
 return fields;
}

int main()
...




if (score[relplayers] == goodfields())
        {
            printf("Player %d is boosted 5 fields backwards", playershown);
            score[relplayers] = score[relplayers] - 5;
        }
         if (score[relplayers] == goodfields())
        {
            printf("Player %d is boosted 5 fields forwards", playershown);
            score[relplayers] = score[relplayers] + 5;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is C, not C++. I assume you actually want C.

I´ve found following problems:

You´re using `scanf` wrong. Eg. if `allscore` is an integer,
`scanf("%d", allscore);` should be `scanf("%d", &allscore);` (`scanf` is different from `printf` here).

`srand` seeds the PRNG. In many cases, this is something which should be done exactly one time in the whole program. *Not* in each function using random numbers. Change that, because it affects the randomness of your numbers.

If you don´t have a good reason to use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` in main, don´t do it. It´s `exit`, and your case isn´t a failure in my opinion. Use `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`. And at the end of main, there should be return too (for the case the loops finish without being aborted).

In `badfields` and `goodfields`, you´re doing something very strange.

```
int badfields () {
  ...
  int numbers[10] = {rand() % abscore + 1};
  return numbers;
}
```

What should this even do? If you want an array of 10 random numbers, the initialization is wrong, and even more important you´re returning an address instead of some generated random number. The next problem is that `numbers` is local; if you intend to return multiple values you´ll get problems here too.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I am sorry about these stupid mistakes of scanf or   return. Do you know what i did wrong with the sum of score[relplayer] = score[relplayer] + thrown. Because somehow i get the first result of 2686716 with every player. And with the good and badfields, I tried to get 10 fields that do smth. bad/good and save them in an array, so that later I can take these numbers and asign them a bad/good thing. But I don't knew how to do that really. I am still new to this programming thing

Comment: Ok forget the score[relplayer] thing I already solved that. But could someone please tell me how to fix the badfields/goodfields function